# API to stripe make 500

Tags: c#, stripe-payments

That's when i need to use the Stripe API so when i need it, it will go wrong and make mistakes in the Stripe area as you can see here.

i have : v15.6.1 on Stripe.net

Where it goes wrong is here:

```
planservice.Create(new StripePlanCreateOptions()
```

to here:

```
PlanId = abn.PriceValueUnikId };
```

all the value I get by json eg userid, pric and pricId there is content in them.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] JObject token)
{
var api = Settings.ConstName.StrinpAPIKeyTest;
StripeConfiguration.SetApiKey(api);
var chargeService = new StripeChargeService();
chargeService.ExpandBalanceTransaction = true;
chargeService.ExpandCustomer = true;
chargeService.ExpandInvoice = true;

//StripeCharge stripeCharge = chargeService.Get(api);

var customerSerive = new StripeCustomerService(api);
var subservice = new StripeSubscriptionService(api);
var planservice = new StripePlanService(api);

var pricId = (int)token.GetValue("pricid");
var pric = (int)token.GetValue("pric");
var userid = (int) Userid();

var abn = _dbContext.PriceValue.FirstOrDefault(i => i.PriceValueId == pricId || i.Price == pric);
//Finder information omkring pakken til den enkelte pakke.

var currentUser = _dbContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(i => i.UserId == userid);
if (currentUser != null)
{
    if (abn != null)
    {
        var orderid = Settings.ValueWordsAndNumbers.OrdreValue();//Orderid
        var planType = $"OrderId: {orderid} - Pris: {abn.Price} - Mdr: {abn.Months} UserId: {userid}";

        planservice.Create(new StripePlanCreateOptions()//error from here
        {
            Amount = int.Parse(abn.Price.ToString()) * 100,
            Nickname = planType,
            Currency = "dkk",
            Interval = "month",
            IntervalCount = abn.Months,
            Id = abn.PriceValueUnikId 
        });

        var newCustomer = new StripeCustomerCreateOptions
        {
            SourceToken = token["id"].ToString(),
            Email = token["email"].ToString(),
            PlanId = abn.PriceValueUnikId,
        };//error to here

        var stripeCustomer = customerSerive.Create(newCustomer);

    }
}
```

Comment: remove your '$' at `$"OrderId: {orderid} - Pris: {abn.Price} - Mdr: {abn.Months} UserId: {userid}";
`

Comment: `new StripeCustomerCreateOptions` > `new StripeCustomerCreateOptions()`

Comment: Also you need another parameter(which is actually required) `Product`. Example: `Product = new StripePlanProductCreateOptions() {
    Name = "Platinum personal"
  },` inside your `new StripePlanCreateOptions()`. See [link](https://stripe.com/docs/api/dotnet#create_plan)

Comment: oh, I can see now. That's to say, I will not create StripeCustomerCreateOptions? @KlevinDelimeta

Comment: depends on what you trying to achieve. if you want to create/get the user, 'in this particular scenario(use-case)' then this is ok

Comment: else no need for that, and just continue with `var planService = new StripePlanService();
StripePlan plan = planService.Create(planOptions);` because this part is needed to(and not included in your posted code)

Comment: Ok. so i took a deeper look, looks like you are trying to create users, and plans in this code. Is this what you want to achieve? if yes, you need to continue and finish the 'creation of plans'.

Comment: Okay cool :) so stripe have make this more easy :P

Comment: Ok :) . So you seem to be on the right track. Good.

Comment: If I just walk into the strip dashboard and check then I can not see that I've created it. hmm @KlevinDelimeta

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169621/discussion-between-klevin-delimeta-and-j-petersen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var planOptions = new StripePlanCreateOptions() {
  Product = new StripePlanProductCreateOptions() {
    Name = "planType"
  },
        Amount = int.Parse(abn.Price.ToString()) * 100,
        Nickname = planType,
        Currency = "dkk",
        Interval = "month",
        IntervalCount = abn.Months,
};

var planService = new StripePlanService();
StripePlan plan = planService.Create(planOptions);
```

Answer (score -1):

[API version to 2018-02-06 and add support for Product & Plan API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_plan)

Now Product is REQUIRED.
you need past ID product or  dictionary containing fields used to create a service product.

```
var planOptions = new StripePlanCreateOptions() {
  ProductId ="Product Plan id",
        Amount = int.Parse(abn.Price.ToString()) * 100,
        Nickname = planType,
        Currency = "dkk",
        Interval = "month",
        IntervalCount = abn.Months,
};
```

Comment: Or user product id     new StripePlanCreateOptions(){                       ProductId = "id",